# Let X’s rank is R, the k boys’ rank must vary between R-k and R+k. First find the (Rk) th and (R+k) th ranked element using Selection

Tags: algorithm, sorting, logic, time-complexity

**This is the question**
*There are n students in a class. The test results are out and assume, for your convenience,
that all the students had distinct grades (numbers). You can think of the test result as an
unsorted integer array. A student X has been told that his rank in the class is R (R is an
integer and obviously, 1 <= R <= n). He wants to find out the k boys who are ranked
closest to him (k/2 students below him, and k/2 students above). Devise an efficient
algorithm to identify the scores of these k boys.*

**It was explained in answer that the time (R-k)th and (R+k)th element can be found out by selection sort
1. How to find the (R-k) th and (R+k)th element using selection sort?
2.How is the run time linear?**

Answer (score 0):

For an unsorted array, there exists a linear selection algorithm to find the ith smallest element of the array.[1]

Assuming k is even, you can find the (R-k/2)th and (R+k/2)th element in linear time.

Regarding your question, if the answer you mentioned is [2], selection should be selection algorithm instead of selection sort.

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm
2. https://www.cise.ufl.edu/class/cot5405sp10/practiceProblems/fa04/2004_fall_exam1_sol.pdf